# Check if integers within an array are within the range

Tags: java, arrays, integer, range

Basically, the program I am supposed to write is to get the energy usage from the customer for 12 months and then output the total usage, price for two tariffs (the formulas are included in the code) and say which tariff is cheaper. But it also has to check whether the input for each of those 12 months is within the range (greater than "0" AND less or equal to "1000").
I have found a fairly easy(?) way to do it using arrays, however I have no idea how to check whether each one of the integers scanned to be in that array are actually within the range 0 < int <= 1000

If the integer is less than 0 or greater than 1000, the program has to output a line "Please enter a valid amount" and ask for the same integer again, so that it doesn't store the wrong value, if it makes sense?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EnergyConsumptionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int total_usage;
        float t1_cost, t2_cost;
        final int MAX_USAGE = 1000, MIN_USAGE = 0;

        int[] energyCons = new int[12];

        for (int month = 0; month < energyCons.length; month++) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the monthly kWh usage for month ");
            System.out.print((month + 1) + ": ");
            energyCons[month] = scan.nextInt();
        }

        int totalCons = 0;
        for (int month = 0; month < energyCons.length; month++) {
            totalCons += energyCons[month];
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total usage for the year was " + totalCons + " kWh");

        t1_cost = (float) (totalCons * 0.1);
        t2_cost = (float) ((totalCons * 0.09) + 50);

        System.out.println("Using tariff one, the cost is: " + t1_cost);
        System.out.println("Using tariff two, the cost is: " + t2_cost);
        System.out.println();

        if (t1_cost > t2_cost) {
            System.out.println("Tariff two would be cheaper for this customer.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tariff one would be cheaper for this customer.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, you do far more advanced things already within this program that checking if one number is greater than/less that annother. Is the problem actually repeatedly asking for input until a valid output is reached? If so a do-while loop should solve your problem

Comment: Without giving too much away, you will need an if() statement to check the number being given to you, every time the user enters a number.

Comment: @DoubleDouble thanks for the fast reply, however, I have tried doing it the other way before. What I did was make an if-statement for each one of 12 months, but it just looks too long and complicated that way. On yesterday's lecture our professor taught us how to use arrays and I thought it might be possible to apply the range to the whole array which would basically just save up loads of space in my java file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your input reading loop to something like this:

```
for (int month = 0; month < energyCons.length; month++) {
  System.out.print("Please enter the monthly kWh usage for month ");
  System.out.print((month + 1) + ": ");
  int inputValue = scan.nextInt();
  while (inputValue < 0 || inputValue > 1000) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid amount: ");
    inputValue = scan.nextInt();
  }
  energyCons[month] = inputValue;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a tiny mistake in the code.
It works perfectly, thank you very much for the quick and helpful reply!!!